# Cannot resolve symbol dataSnapShot

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I  am trying to pass a value retrieved from my Firebase database. This line of code is causing the error `Cannot resolve symbol dataSnapShot`

```
     File  o2 = retrieveFromFirebase.onCreate()onDataChange(dataSnapshot);
```

all my Firebase imports are unused

Comment: This doesn't look familiar to me. Can you give a link to the API that you're trying to use?